# How to run computationally expensive task on serial port data outside UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, serial-port

I have a WPF application written in C# that provides a GUI for communication with some equipment on the serial port. he GUI contains a raw output field where characters are shown as they come in, and a section where the data is presented filtered and processed. Sometimes (when stuff goes wrong with my external equipment) a lot of data comes in and the program locks up intermittently.

This is what my code looks like in a nutshell:

```
 private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
 {
   // get string out of buffer
   // do filtering and processing (see details in text below)

   UIdispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, callbackFunctionInUIThread, processedData);
 }
```

Each time data comes in, some filtering and processing needs to be done: I dig through a queue of incoming data to search for packages of a custom communication protocol. If a package is found, some more work is done. This presents me with two options:

1. Do the filtering/processing inside the event handler. Results in delayed presentation of raw data and/or freezing up of everything when processing takes too long.
2. Do the filtering/processing in the UI thread. Results in the UI locking up.

I would prefer to pass the raw data to the UI directly, and have a separate filtering and processing thread that works on the data in FIFO fashion. The serial port DataReceivedHandler would push data into the processing queue and another thread would continuously process the queue and pass any results off to the UI for presentation (or go to sleep when the queue is empty).

How can I implement this? The System.Threading namespace is full of cool sounding classes, but I couldn't find anything that seems applicable to what I am trying to do :(

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have an IDE handy but you could use [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) and [Task.Factory.StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd321439.aspx)

Something like this :

```
public class WorkItem //or use your SerialDataReceivedEventArgs 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string SomeData {get;set;}
}
```

Then

```
private ConcurrentQueue<WorkItem> WorkItems  = new ConcurrentQueue<WorkItem>();
private CancellationTokenSource WorkTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
private AutoResetEvent ResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);

void Main()
{

    StartProcessingWork();
    for (var x = 0;x<1000;x++)
    {
        QueueWorkItem(new WorkItem(){Id= x,SomeData=String.Format("Item : {0}",x)});
    }

    Timer addItems = new Timer((a)=>
    {
        QueueWorkItem(new WorkItem(){Id= 0,SomeData=DateTime.Now.ToString()});
    });

    addItems.Change(1000,1000);

    Timer cancel = new Timer((a)=>{
        WorkTokenSource.Cancel();
        ResetEvent.Set();
        addItems.Change(Timeout.Infinite,Timeout.Infinite);
    });
    cancel.Change(5000,0);

}


public void StartProcessingWork()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew((o)=>
    {
        while(!WorkTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            WorkItem item = null;
            if (WorkItems.TryDequeue(out item))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Processing...");
                ProcessWorkItem(item);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
                ResetEvent.WaitOne();
            }
        }
    },WorkTokenSource.Token,TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}



private void ProcessWorkItem(WorkItem item)
{
    //Do some work here...
    for (var x=0;x<100000;x++)
    {
        item.Id = x; //blah blah blah
    }

    //Use dispatcher to display
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>DisplayWorkItem(item));
}

private void DisplayWorkItem(WorkItem item)
{
    //DO your display logic here...
}

public void QueueWorkItem(WorkItem item)
{
    WorkItems.Enqueue(item);
    ResetEvent.Set();
}
```